# Recommend to track all logins, update login table, or both?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, ip-address

Currently I am having a hard time deciding/weighing the pros/cons of tracking login information for a member website.

### Currently

I have two tables, login_i and login_d.

- login_i contains the member's id, password, last login datetime, and total count of logins. (member id is primary key and obviously unique so one row per member)
- login_d contains a list of all login data in history which tracks each and every time a login occurs. It contains member's id, datetime of login, ip_address of login. This table's primary key is simply an auto-incremented INT field, really purposeless but need a primary and the only unique single field (an index on the otherhand is different but still not concerned).

In many ways I see these tables as being very similar but the benefit of having the latter is to view exactly when a member logged in, how many times, and which IP it came from. All of the information in login_i (last login and count) truthfully exists in login_d but in a more concise form without ever needing to calculate a COUNT(*) on the latter table.

Does anybody have advice on which method is preferred? Two tables will exist regardless but should I keep record of last_login and count in login_i at all if login_d exists?

### added thought/question

good comment made below - what about also tracking login attempts based on a username/email/ip? Should this ALSO be stored in a table (a 3rd table I assume).

Comment: I was wondering the same. Big Coincidence. I was thinking in login_attempts too. Good question btw.

Comment: @santiagobasulto - great point about login attempts. I have something similar for security on intranet applications I run but is certainly valuable information to have!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is called denormalization.

you ideally would never denormalize.

it is sometimes done anyway to save on computationally expensive results - possibly like your total login count value.

the downside is that you may at some point get into a situation where the value in one table does not match the values in the other table(s).  of course you will try your best to keep them properly up to date, but sometimes things happen.  In this case, you will possibly generate bugs in application logic if they receive an incorrect value from one of the sources.

In this specific case, a count of logins is probably not that critical to the successful running of the app - so not a big risk - although you will still have the overhead of maintaining the value.

Comment: one final thought - denormalizing here feels like premature optimization.  I would not do it, but if you find at some point that you are seeing performance issues, then go ahead and change strategies.

Comment: great point and thank you for the technical term for what I am trying to accomplish. I believe storing in two tables is necessary, still not entirely sure if I want to keep last_login in login_i but may have to dwell more. I am interested to hear other responses.

Comment: i agree, if you need it a lot and it isn't critical then store the 'dupes' in login_i. to ease maintenance, you could try a trigger on insertion into login_d to count++ and set new time in login_i.

Answer (score 0):

Do you often need last login and count? If Yes, then you should store it in login_i aswell. If it's rarely used then you can take your time process the query in the giant table of all logins instead of storing duplicated data.

Comment: good point but to be honest, it is an application in such early stages, I am not sure how often we will need it. I think it is much simpler to run a (select * from login_i where total_count > X) rather than a more complicated (and costly) subquery/join set to calculate the logins for potentially tens of thousands of members.